# How to add right click menu like dropbox for my specific application

Tags: macos, menu, right-click

Problem:
I need to have a right click menu on a specific folder, that shows my application submenu. Something like dropbox does.

I did try to google a lot and found Services which provides to create right click menu, but it creates generic menu not on a specific file or folder. How does dropbox does it? Does it use some python script? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Kapil